# Android RelativeLayout Transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-view, transparent

I can't get my relativelayout to be able to be set to transparent. I have tried many different methods, custom view from class, adding android:background="@android:color/transparent" etc. They either show a white like in the picture below, or they show a solid color of whatever the hex is?

[image]

Even programmatically using '.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);' results in the above picture.

Comment: There must be something on the background, if you set background of root layout as transparent you will see only default background color.

Comment: hi, this is not a comment related to your question, but can you tell me how to have cards in app? do you use nadav fimas library? or anything other

Comment: @MaulikSheth Google 'android listview card style'. Its simply a background for each item. You can customize it to look exactly like a card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The main LinearLayout of my view was the layout making it have a white background. I added my view under my listview in a RelativeLayout and it works great. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `#AARRGGBB` instead of `#RRGGBB`

**Do this as following:**

```
android:background="#AARRGGBB"
```

**becomes:**

```
android:background="#77000000"
```

The first 2 (AA) will set the transparancy. Set 77 to 00 for `zero transparancy`,

Comment: No luck, tried it several times like that. Even setting it programmatically with no luck. I am using an <include> on my layout if it makes any difference.